# pushing to git remote branch

Tags: git, github

I could use a hand with learning how to push a local branch to a remote branch. Please see below. Help much appreciated!

The local branch was created after cloning the repo then doing

```
$ git checkout -b mybranch remotes/origin/mybranch

$ git branch -a
  master
* mybranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mybranch
```

But when trying to push changes back up:

```
$ git push mybranch mybranch
fatal: 'mybranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git push remotes/origin/mybranch mybranch
fatal: 'mybranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git push origin/mybranch mybranch
fatal: 'mybranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try

```
git push origin mybranch
```

This pushes your branch named **mybranch** to the remote named **origin**

Answer (score 94):

As Abizern says, this works:

```
git push origin mybranch
```

But, to explain further, the *mybranch* part is a *refspec*. This specifies the remote ref which should be updated with the given local commit.

So, the command above is equivalent to:

```
git push origin mybranch:mybranch
```

or even:

```
git push origin mybranch:refs/heads/mybranch
```

and, indeed, since you're on the local mybranch, you could have done:

```
git push origin HEAD:mybranch
```

This is good to understand, because I often find myself doing things like:

```
git push origin HEAD^:mybranch
```

where you want to push all but the topmost patch to the remote branch.

Finally, if you want to delete the remote mybranch, you do:

```
git push origin :mybranch
```

Comment: Because the refspec is <src>:<dst>, by leaving off the <src> part, this basically says to make the topic branch on the remote nothing, which deletes it. [source](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html) - last paragraph

Comment: @JeremyIglehart Do you have an updated link? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @cambunctious It looks like they updated the book and reorganized the chapters. It's now in [Chapter 10.5](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#_deleting_references) under "Deleting References" – This also referenced in the [git-push documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) under the <refspec> option.  Look for "Pushing an empty <src> allows you to delete the <dst> ref from the remote repository."  Hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, [Chapter 10.5](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#_deleting_references) is "Git Internals", "The Refspec" – just in case the Chapters get renumbered in the future, so that people can find it.  (I didn't get back here soon enough to edit my comment)

Comment: I was slightly confused by "topic branch". It's not a technical term, but just the name of the branch in the example in the Git book. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but I used this page as a ref back in the day, and have an answer with a different perspective. From my experience, the best way is to tweak your config settings such that a `git push` is all that you will have to enter in the end.

You will push to the same remote branch that you update your code from:

- `git config --global push.default upstream`

And now, you set the remote branch as upstream (if it wasn't already):

- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/the_master`
- NOTE: Older versions can fall back upon this deprecated form of the command/.
- `git branch --set-upstream local_branch origin/the_master`

You have two branches - a local and a remote. Doing a `git pull` or `git push` without args should, and will now, do what you want. This will not limit you to pushing to remote branches with the same name as the local one, as some of the above commands do.

One final thing I usually do: modify `git pull` to change from this sequence:

- `git fetch && git merge [remote_upstream]` to
- `git fetch && git rebase [remote_upstream]`

With this command: `git config --global branch.autosetuprebase remote`